# Angular join multiple fields to one field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried to find article to copy value in each of fields to another field using angular.

I want to get start_date value by joining day, month, and year fields so it will show `2016/1/2`.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="profesional in jobseeker.professionals">
  <div class="infoDateBox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="DD" ng-model="profesional.start_dd">
    <input type="text" placeholder="MM" ng-model="profesional.start_mm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="YYYY" ng-model="profesional.start_yyyy">
  </div>
  <span class="seperator">-</span>
  <tr>
    <td>Start date</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="professional.start_date" ng-value="professional.start_yyyy + '/' + professional.start_mm + '/' + professional.start_dd"></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('hiredtoday')
  .controller('SmartPofileUpdateCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $state, $stateParams, SmartProfile) {
    $scope.jobseeker = SmartProfile.get({id: $stateParams.id});
  })
```

I use `ng-value` to get data from anther field but it does not update the `ng-model`
 of `professional.start_date`

If you have another options, I need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Can I see your controller?

Comment: @Luke101 I have updated it. I need to copy month, day, and year to start_date field. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If my answer is correct, please mark it as correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try achieve this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/57js5ydo/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.profesional ={};
  $scope.setStartDate = function(){
  $scope.professional.start_date = $scope.professional.start_yyyy + '/' + $scope.professional.start_mm + '/' + $scope.professional.start_dd;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="infoDateBox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="DD" ng-change="setStartDate()" ng-model="professional.start_dd">
    <input type="text" placeholder="MM" ng-change="setStartDate()" ng-model="professional.start_mm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="YYYY" ng-change="setStartDate()" ng-model="professional.start_yyyy">
  </div>
  <span class="seperator">-</span>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Start date</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="professional.start_date">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello @stepan. It will accept you answer because it helps me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, professional spelling is wrong in the first three inputs model's.

Now to answer your question, the problem with your approach is, you are using 4 different properties to store/refer 1 value i.e, the date. It is not pure angular way as far as I know.

You need to store it in only 1 property i.e, professional.start_date and then split the date month and year from the same until and unless you really have some thing to do separately with the date month and year. I hope I am clear. Please read below.

`ngModelController` gives us `$formatters` and `$parsers`, which format/parse your model/view and present them to the view or store them back to the model accordingly. You should use them actually. Implementation below.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController">
<div class="infoDateBox">
  <input dd-directive type="text" placeholder="DD" ng-model="professional.start_date">
  <input mm-directive type="text" placeholder="MM" ng-model="professional.start_date">
  <input yyyy-directive type="text" placeholder="YYYY" ng-model="professional.start_date">
</div>
<span class="seperator">-</span>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Start date</td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="professional.start_date"></td>
</tr>
</table>
    <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript  "></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript  "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.professional = {};
  $scope.professional.start_date = new Date();
});


myApp.directive('yyyyDirective', function($filter)
{
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController)
    {
      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data)
      {
        return $filter('date')(data, "yyyy");  
      });

      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data)
      {
        var d = new Date(ngModelController.$modelValue);
        d.setYear(data);
        return d;
      });
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('mmDirective', function($filter)
{
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController)
    {
      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data)
      {
        return data.getMonth()+1; 
      });

      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data)
      {
        console.log(data);
        var d = new Date(ngModelController.$modelValue);
        if(data.length!=0)
        {
          d.setMonth(parseInt(data)-1);
        }
        else
        {
          d.setMonth(0);
        }
        return d;
      });
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('ddDirective', function($filter)
{
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController)
    {
      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data)
      {
        return $filter('date')(data, "dd");  
      });

      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data)
      {
        var d = new Date(ngModelController.$modelValue);
        d.setDate(data);
        return d;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This code can be optimized but I wrote it that way for understanding purpose. Let me know if you have any doubts. Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: Thanks you for your help. It is nice solution.